# Windows logon custom wallpaper cached issue

Tags: windows, login, desktop-customization

I've managed to change windows logon wallpaper via `regedit`: setting `OEMBackground` to hexadecimal value equal to 1 and creating defaultWallpaper file in `c:\Windows\System32\oobe\info\backgrounds\`.

But somehow this wallpaper was cached, and replacing file with new one doesn't change logon wallpaper. Can you please advise what possible can cause this issue?

Comment: Is this a machine that you have limited access to? The below tool works very well if you can run it:
http://www.julien-manici.com/windows_7_logon_background_changer/

Comment: Nope, I'm local administrator on that machine.

Comment: I changed mine , and it changed back , changed it again and a few months later it decided to return. Eventually it stuck forever. I don't know why, I just persisted and it finnaly stuck.

Comment: @Psycogeek the same is true for me. Whatever image I copy to that directory nothing changes.

Comment: The image has to have a specific name? backgroundDefault.jpg is what name I use, and it Must be smaller than 250KB if i remember right.

Comment: @Psycogeek it is, still the same.

Comment: So is the registry change itself turning back?

Comment: @Psycogeek, yes, it reverts wallpaper to default one.

Comment: All i can tell you is to change it again, then reboot the computer right after, that way the registry will be saved out fully (as opposed to crashing). Then do it again if needed. I use a simple import script, but i have not needed it in quite some time.  Possible that some repairs and restores could retract that easily also, i do not think it does it on its own.